# How to print html as plain text as xml parser?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, web

Firstly sorry for my english! not so good.

But basically, i want to get html from http://st.chatango.com/profileimg/k/p/kpyto/mod1.xml in javascript. The body tag, and i've managed to do that, i also unescaped the encoded text.

So it will display, but when i print it on the screen it show as html and renders it. 
I want to see the html as just text.
If anyone can help me, that would be awesome :)

my html file:

http://pastebin.com/Y4t28mEM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform an HTML entity encode on the text before displaying it.

Replace:

```
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML=txt;
```

With:

```
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = txt.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
    return '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';';
});
```